# Get Attribute XML in JTree

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtree

In this [tutorial](http://naveedmurtuza.blogspot.com/2010/10/display-xml-in-jtree-with-dnd-support.html), how I get attribute of xml when I right click delete menu, then show the dialog with the value of attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `deleteAction`, you can reference `clickedPath.getLastPathComponent()` to access the selected node.