# How to refresh XML in Jtree

Tags: java, xml, swing, reload, jtree

I read  [here](http://naveedmurtuza.blogspot.com/2010/10/display-xml-in-jtree-with-dnd-support.html) ,  but if the xml file changes the jtree does not reload /refreshes
how to create a function for refresh / reload Jtree
I try to write code :

```
refreshAction = new AbstractAction("Refresh", IconFactory.getIcon("delete", IconFactory.IconSize.SIZE_16X16)) {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    XMLTree xmlClass = null;
    ((DefaultTreeModel) xmlClass.getModel()).reload(); 
    System.out.println("Refresh");
}};
```

but i got the error : java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a new `Action` to `popup` in `getJPopupForExplorerTree()`. You'll probably want to re-factor `xmlFile` out of the `XMLTree` constructor; I've hard coded it for expedience below:

```
popup.add(new AbstractAction("Reload") {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Reload");
        try {
            root = getRoot("xml.xml");
            setModel(new XMLTreeModel(root));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Glad to help; also consider a [`WatchService`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7784909/230513).

Answer (score 2):

- this is most complex code, probably
- read tutorial about `JTables DefaultTableModel` (good described concept and logics for `DefaultXxxModel` is similair / the same)
- read tutorial about `JTree`
- read tutorial about `Concurency in Swing`,
- especially description about `SwingWorker`
- in your case better (sorry for that) would be create an new instance for `DefaultTreeModel`, fills data by using `SwingWorker`, add new model to the visible `JTree`,
- by replacing model you'll lost all changes in the current `JTree`

Comment: @BujanganMuda: I think you'll have to refresh the model from the file, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11875615/230513).

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the spesific code but you can try this

```
refreshAction = new AbstractAction("Refresh", IconFactory.getIcon("delete", IconFactory.IconSize.SIZE_16X16)) {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     DefaultTreeModel myTreeModel = (DefaultTreeModel) xmlClass.getModel();

     myTreeModel.reload();

     revalidate();
     repaint();
}};
```

Comment: Good idea, but I think he'll have to refresh the model from the file, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11875615/230513). BujanganMuda: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11790390/230513).