# How we implement .xml file using java in swing application?

Tags: java, html, xml, swing

I am working in a swing application.There is a Expandable tree view in which when we  right click on  it we get options to select. If i choose action from it, i get a pop-up and can select the appropriate action from the drop down options.

Now i tried to search in my whole projcect where the drop-down options are written in source code and i found it only in .html and .xml file. In .xml file it was like this..

In another .xml file it expandale tree view was written like this.

```
<indexitem text="expandable tree view, about" target="d0e60"/>
<indexitem text="expandable tree view, actions" target="d0e91"/>
```

How these are implemented? Actually i am clueless about how these .java,.html,.xml files interact to produce such kind of swing application? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`XMLTree`](http://naveedmurtuza.blogspot.com/2010/10/display-xml-in-jtree-with-dnd-support.html), mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11875615/230513), is an example that reads nodes from the file `xml.xml`.