# From text file to tree structure view using jtree

Tags: java, swing, treeview, jtree, directory-structure

I am using JTree to build folder tree structure(GUI), I can build it manually if I know proper file structure. I want to implement this structure reading structure specified in text file, which is dynamic. I am bit poor in coding recursion type problems. Please help me

If in text file structure is as shown below

### label - level

root - 0
LivingBeings - 1
animals - 2
dog - 3
cat - 3
birds - 2
peacock - 3
crow - 3

I need a tree structure like as shown in image[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should consider implementing the [`TreeModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#data) interface. As an example, [`FileTreeModel`](https://dzone.com/articles/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-), cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13258638/230513), works with either `JTree`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14837208/230513), or `Outline`, as shown [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui/4447#4447).

See also `XMLTree`, which reads nodes from an XML file, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11875615/230513).