# Custom Java Swing XML Editor

Tags: java, xml, swing, jaxb

I need to show an xml as a tree structure in a java swing application. When I click on any node in the swing tree its attribute should list in a window (like a properties editor) and from that I need to update the attributes. Also I need to hide some nodes in the xml in the tree.

I am planning to use `JTree` to populate  and show the xml as tree. But bit confused about what approach need to take to read/update the xml.
Currently I have the below options:

1. Using JAXB create the corresponding objects and populate the JTree
2. Use any parser DOM or SAX and populate the JTree using the DefaultMutableTreeNode

Please advice what approach I need to proceed? or is there any other better way for doing this?

Comment: It depends, either DOM or SAX would be preferred as it will provide you with the raw information you need and the ability to filter the content as required...

Comment: A related example is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11841117/230513).